# labels does not show and my progress bar is vertical

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

two questions:

First: My progress bar is vertical when I load my app, however it is horizontal in my view in Xcode (as I want it to be)
How can I make it horizontal when the app is loaded?

second: I have several labels which are working fine, however the last 3 labels I have added won't show up when my app is loaded, even though I haven't changed them with any code whatsoever..  I must have clicked something in Xcode, I guess?

Comment: may i ask if you are using autolayout properly?

Comment: I'am completely new to Xcode and swift (and programming in general), and I'm not sure what you are referring to by auto layout ?

On my main story board if I "update all frames" everything look like it should... but when I run my app, the last 3 labels I have added are not showing and my progress bar will go vertical (instead of horizontal)

Comment: This looks to me like an auto layout issue. May i suggest you have a look here : http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2
They do have a good tutorial for new to swift programming to learn the basics of autolayout. Autolayout helps you have the same layout for all iPhone and iPad devices. It's a dynamic constraint system with which when you place a label in a view it will stay in the same position no matter what device you are using

Comment: I have made acceptble constraints in wANY, hANY... so I don't think this is the problem... I have an strange feeling that it might be my background picture that its in the front of them, but I checked that too...